# Adding brackets [] to the attribute in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to set a state that I'm getting from an input target:

Below is the code for my constructor and the method which updates the target's state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        title: ''
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

    onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] :  e.target.value
    });
}
```

Where the input is given by this code:

```
<input type={"text"} name={"title"} value={this.state.title} onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

When I debug my code I found that e.target.name contains "title" and I do not understanding why I need the squared brackets `[]` in `[e.target.name]` ... I found some explanation on the web but I have not understood what it means:

> We use attr in this.setState with square brackets [ ] because [ ] lets
>   us query object key names programmatically (similar to how array[2] or
>   object[keyA] works)

Can you help me to understand why we need these brackets ?

FYI : If I remove the brackets as this :

```
onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            e.target.name : e.target.value
        });
    }
```

this give me this error : "Unexpected token, expected" at  e.target.name

[image]

Comment: you dont need the braces around strings

Comment: you dont need the [] you just need it when accessing something off a property user[some varible i want to load ]

Comment: It gives me error if I dont put the brackets -- I ll add this to my post

Comment: i mean `name = "whatever"` in the react constructor

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This syntax is just another way to set a key of an object without knowing ahead of time what you want it to be called -- a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

For instance, these two examples accomplish the same thing:

```
const myNewObject = {
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 30
}
```

…

```
const propName = 'age'

const myNewObject = {
  name: 'Joe',
  [propName]: 30
}
```

So in your example– `e.target.name` comes from the `name` attribute of the input element ("title", in this case). By setting the state's key with `[e.target.name]` you're really just setting the `title` property of the state.

Answer (score 3):

```
  { sth: else }
```

is equal to

```
  { ["sth"]: else }
```

or

```
  var id = "sth";

 { [id]: else }
```

So you basically need it when you want to evaluate the identifier instead of taking it.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I updated my post ... this is not working in my case

Comment: @taboubim yes i know.